# Обобщённый Query в Mediatr

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, mediatr

Столкнулся с вот какой проблемой переделывая репозиторий на CQS.

Был метод выбирающий из базы контакты по предикату и сортирующий по определённому полю:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Contact>> GetAsync(Expression<Func<Contact, bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<Contact, TOrderKey>> orderBy, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return await this.ApplicationDbContext.Contacts
                     .Include(x => x.ApplicationUser.City)
                     .Where(predicate)
                     .OrderBy(orderBy)
                     .AsNoTracking()
                     .ToArrayAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

Работает, всё окей. Стал переносить в Mediatr - понял, что не понимаю, как мне написать обобщённый запрос (никогда не делал) и что-то не нахожу примеров.

Я так понимаю, что должно быть как-то так:

Запрос:

```
public class Query<TOrderKey> : IRequest<IEnumerable<Contact>>
    where TOrderKey : class
{
    public Query(Expression<Func<Contact, bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<Contact, TOrderKey>> orderBy)
    {
        this.Predicate = predicate;
        this.OrderBy = orderBy;
    }

    public Expression<Func<Contact, bool>> Predicate { get; }

    public Expression<Func<Contact, TOrderKey>> OrderBy { get; }
}
```

Обработчик:

```
public class Handler<TOrderKey> : BaseHandler, IRequestHandler<Query<TOrderKey>, IEnumerable<Contact>>
    where TOrderKey : class
{
    public Handler(ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext)
        : base(applicationDbContext)
    {
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Contact>> Handle(Query<TOrderKey> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await this.ApplicationDbContext.Contacts
                         .Include(x => x.ApplicationUser.City)
                         .Where(request.Predicate)
                         .OrderBy(request.OrderBy)
                         .AsNoTracking()
                         .ToArrayAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

И оно даже компилируется... но падает в рантайме при попытке вызова с ошибкой:

```
Expression<Func<Contact, bool>> expr = x => x.OwnerId == request.UserID;

if (request.Filter.CityId != null)
{
    Expression<Func<Contact, bool>> exprCity = x => x.ApplicationUser.CityId == request.Filter.CityId;
    expr = expr.AndAlso(exprCity);
}

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(request.Filter.SearchText))
{
    Expression<Func<Contact, bool>> exprText = x => x.DisplayName.Contains(request.Filter.SearchText) || x.Notes.Contains(request.Filter.SearchText);
    expr = expr.AndAlso(exprText);
}

return this.Mediator.Send(new Contacts.List.Query<string>(expr, x => x.DisplayName));
```

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> InvalidOperationException: Handler was not found for request of type
>   MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[Application.Contacts.List.Query`1[System.String],System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Domain.Models.Contact]].
>   Register your handlers with the container. See the samples in GitHub
>   for examples.
>
> MediatR.Internal.RequestHandlerBase.GetHandler(ServiceFactory
>   factory)

Регистрация mediatr в Startup.cs самая обычная, все остальные обработчики находятся без проблем:

```
services.AddMediatR(typeof(Application.City.Create.Command).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
```

[Здесь](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/issues/24#issuecomment-412066034) указывается, что для того, чтобы generic handler работали - нужно в первую очередь, чтобы применённый в проекте DI контейнер поддерживал динамическую диспетчеризацию (polymorphic dispatch).  У меня используется рекомендованный для .net core [MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection) и у него такая поддержка заявлена (см. на заглавной репозитория: "Supports generic variance of handlers.")

Однако у меня обобщённый не только handler, но и query.

Как правильно делать подобные запросы в mediatr?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53895522/add-a-generic-handler-for-send-and-publish-methods-of-the-mediatr-library-in-asp

Comment: @A K, точно такая возникла задача как вы её решили? У меня есть обобщённый Query и мне надо сделать обобщённый Handler